# Getting stuff out from QueryDict

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Right now I have a `QueryDict` from a `POST` request, but I'm not sure how to extract the values given that the param can change.

Example: `QueryDictEx = {"field1": "field2"}`

The problem is that the user can input `field1` based on what they want, and I'm not sure how I would retrieve the name of the first part. If it's static, like `"user"` or `"password"` i can just do `QueryDictEx.get("user")` and be done with it, but since that can change base on user, I'm stuck on what to do.

Comment: what are the possible values? You could set the rules based on criteria, that way you have more control over the application.

Comment: What do you hope to do with them? Yes you can iterate over the key/values but whether or not that is useful depends on what you need them for

Answer (score 1):

`QueryDict` is inheriting from python `dict` so you should be able to iterate just as a `dict`:

```
for key, value in request.POST.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

Comment: I just realized what's wrong. For some reason my `request.POST` is returning an empty `QueryDict`, but `request.body` gives me something that looks like a `Dict` but when I do `type(request.body)` it gives me that the type is a string... So the string looks like `{"test1": "test2", "test3": "test4"}`

Comment: I don't understand why do you use `request` like that and how did those information end up being in the `request.body`. You shouldn't be using other fields to pass data around. You need to edit you question to post some relevant code so we understand it better.